# Where to release the CFStringRef in this code

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I have the following piece of code. I am a bit unsure about retain/release concepts.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(urls)  ; i++) {
    CFStringRef url = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(urls, i);
    CFStringRef urlType = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(urls, i);
    urlString  = (NSString *)url;
    urlTypeString = (NSString *)urlType;
    if ([urlTypeString hasPrefix:@"_"]) {
        NSString * urlTypeSubString = [urlTypeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, ([urlTypeString length]-8))];
        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL; %@: http://%@",urlTypeSubString,urlString]];
    }else{
        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL; %@: http://%@",urlTypeString,urlString]];
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions.

1. Where should I release 'CFStringRef url' and 'CFStringRef urlType' in this code.
2. Should I release 'urlString' and 'urlTypeString', which are string types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the for...

And take a look at this :  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(urls)  ; i++) 
{
    CFStringRef url = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(urls, i);
    CFStringRef urlType = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(urls, i);
    urlString  = (NSString *)url;
    urlTypeString = (NSString *)urlType;
    if ([urlTypeString hasPrefix:@"_"]) {
        NSString * urlTypeSubString = [urlTypeString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, ([urlTypeString length]-8))];
        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL; %@: http://%@",urlTypeSubString,urlString]];
    }
    else
    {
        [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL; %@: http://%@",urlTypeString,urlString]];
    }
    // Release here
    CFRelease(url);
    CFRelease(urlType);
}
```